# FileNotFoundError while taking input an image in "load_img" in keras in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

FileNotFoundError while taking input an image in "load_img" in keras in jupyter notebook

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,load_img
import json
import requests
import PIL
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img=np.array(load_img("IMG_2996.jpg").resize((224,224))).tolist() #Iam getting problem here,in jupyter notebook it is showing filenotfound


url='http://127.0.0.1:5000/model'


requested_data=json.dumps({'img':img})
response = requests.post(url,requested_data)
response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image file is not in the same directory as your current working directory. This will tell you the directory it's looking for.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Correct your relative path or use an absolute path.